# Eclipse (Kepler) What is required to enable SVN Connector: Under "Team->SVN"?

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I have installed the latest Eclipse (Kepler) into a new directory and can no longer access my repositories through Eclipse.

As far as I can tell, I've set up everything properly after 2 days of trying to fix this.

[image: No! You can't have your repository]
[image: Well yes, everything you need is installed]
[image: What connector?]

wtf?

Should I just ditch the supposedly better, newer Eclipse and go back a step so I can at least work?

Comment: i'm working on MacOs and I got the similar problem. I can't connect to the svn server and here is my question on st:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627554/i-was-getting-an-error-when-trying-to-create-a-svn-repository-location-via-subve  Any idea?

Comment: I eventually resolved the problem by backing up and deleting my workspace. Some configuration and settings were interfering with the updated connector download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important detail in resolving this issue was remembering that I wanted to keep my workspace.
When I decided to start from scratch, I backed up the workspace, and then copied over only the directories that I needed,
instead of the entire workspace as I had been doing.

The result of starting fresh is that some hidden files residing in the old workspace were not longer present and the triggers
for installing the connector executed properly.

everything was fine after that.

Answer (score 28):

I've never had this problem in Linux, but I recently had it in Windows. This is what I did:

1. Go to http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download.php
   ([the link that Dollyn posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17481743/399105))
2. Under the latest **Release**, copy the **Subversive SVN Connectors** URL

   - The current URL for Eclipse 4.3 Kepler: http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/kepler-site/
3. In Eclipse, go to the **Help** menu → **Install New Software...**
4. Click **Add...**
5. In **Location** copy the URL for the Subversive SVN Connectors
6. Click **OK**
7. Check **Subversive SVN Connectors**
8. Click **Next**, and then follow the instructions to complete installation

Comment: Broken link again on 2014-02-01? Could find repository but unable do download from it

Comment: Great, thanks. Selected all SVN connectors, and some of them worked, some didn't. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

you can install the connector here:
http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download.php

Comment: For some reason, I had to do this twice using the update site; Once to install a package called SVN Connectors, and once again after restarting to install the needed connector

Comment: I've just followed the instructions on this website. I installed Subversive using Kepler's official update site and connectors from http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/kepler-site/ . It works!

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same the problem. Solution is simple just **delete metadata folder from current workspace or create the new workspace**.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem was that I needed to clear out my workspace.
The trigger that downloads the connector was not activating.

When I pointed Eclipse to a new workspace, the connector download appeared during the following startup.

Archived my old workspace and slowly adding work in progress.

It's really important to stay organized if one is going to do development on multiple projects at once.

Answer (score 2):

Use this url to install SVN connectors for Eclipse/Kepler

**latest stable release**

http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/4.0/update-site/

Answer (score 1):

Go to the marketplace and search for Subclipse (or another tool) and install it. Next time you open the Team Synchronizing perspective you will have SVN support (not only Git and CVS anymore). You will be able to add SVN repositories as usual in SVN Repository Exploring perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Note for anyone having strange Eclipse plugin install/update problems under Windows: if your normal Windows login does not have Administrator privileges (for security it should not) then Eclipse plugin install/update can break unexpectedly due to file permissions.

An example (misleading) error message when attempting to install SVN connectors is:

```
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector,3.0.1.I20130507-1700
```

In this case, always perform Eclipse plugin install/update as an Administrator and the above-mentioned problems vanish.  I thought I should share this here because the Eclipse error messages can lead you in completely the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

For **Eclipse Kepler** : `http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x`  followed by `http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/kepler-site/` works for me.

Steps are as follows:

1. "Help" -> "Install New Software".
2. Put `http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x` in the "work with" textbox and click on the "Add" button.
3. Select all components and install it.
4. Put `http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/kepler-site/` in the "work with" textbox and click on the "Add" button.
5. Select all components and install it.