# I was getting an error when trying to create a svn repository location via subversive plugin in eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, svn

When try to connect the location:`**http://192.168.87.16:8090/svn/sa/aqua**`

First get the following error:

**Some resources were not updated.
svn: E175002: can not read HTTP status line
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/sa/aqua/trunk/main'**

Then I try to connect again:

**Get repository folder children operation failed.
svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/svn/sa/aqua': 501 Unsupported method (PROPFIND) (`http://192.168.87.16:8090`)**

Before I upgrade to Kepler,I was using Juno and everything was fine.

Is it a bug for subversive in Kepler?

A more detailed pic:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed... Sorry for my careless. I add proxy to the eclipse so it failed to connect the svn server.